# Android Webview "Sandboxing is not allowed" when loading iframe stream

Tags: java, android, html, iframe, webview

I am attempting to load another site's iframe into my android app via webview. I am able to properly load other websites but when I load a stream from sportsbay.org which provides you with an iframe embed code snippet, the stream goes black and it prints "Sandboxing is not allowed". I have gone through several other questions to find an answer to this. My android project is as follows.

The specific url that I am passing in as video_url is https://sportsbay.org/embed/45629/1/btn-big-ten-network-live.html. The iframe snippet that sportsbay provides is `<iframe allow='encrypted-media' width='640' height='360' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='yes' src='//sportsbay.org/embed/45629/1/btn-big-ten-network-live.html'></iframe>`. This url loads two urls 1) https://lowend.xyz/stream/45629.html which is the actual stream and moments later loads 2) https://sportsbay.org/live-streams to redirect you to the home page of sportsbay. I have code in MyWebViewClient that prevents the main sportsbay page from loading which would interrupt the stream I want to play (THIS is where I get the sandboxing message). I have tried replacing loadUrl with loadData and other variations that pass in the iframe html string along with the mimeType but what I have currently is the closest I have come to loading the stream (others don't get far enough to post the sandboxing message).

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Bring Linear layout into view.
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        // Grab current intent & pull out video url.
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String video_url = i.getStringExtra("video_url");
        // Removes app name banner at top. Allows for orientation changes without reload.
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        // Creates webview object.
        WebView web = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        // Configure settings for webview.
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        // Allows use of the phones file storage.
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        // Sets encoding standard for urls.
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        // Able to zoom.
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // Needed for websites to load javascript enabled content (most videos/streams).
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // Attached webview to java class MyWebViewClient that vets the incoming urls before loading.
        // Blocks Ads / viruses / popups.
        // Also keeps url from launch in a browser.
        web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        // Checks if channel is sourced from sportsbay.org.
        if(video_url.contains("sportsbay.org"))
        {
            // Changes the browser user agent since chrome user agent returns 403 Forbidden message.
            webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion");
        }
        web.loadUrl(video_url);
    }
```

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {

        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        return handleUri(uri);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        return handleUri(uri);
    }

    private boolean handleUri(final Uri uri) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Uri =" + uri);
        final String host = uri.getHost();
        final String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        // Check requested URL to known good
        if (host.equals("s1-tv.blogspot.com") ||
            host.equals("reddit-tv-streams.blogspot.com") ||
            host.equals("newdmn.icu") ||
            host.equals("lowend.xyz"))
        {
            // Returning false means that you are going to load this url in the webView itself
            return false;
        } else {
            // Do not load the requested URL
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news! I figured it out. The sandboxing message was not because of the server incorrectly interacting with my app, it was because my app did not have permission to use the file storage outside of the android application (the app sandbox). This was fixed with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

which needs to be placed in the Android Manifest.xml in the permissions area (under the top package).